# Exporting a function from an external file does not work

Tags: node.js, express

I need to export a function from an external file.

```
const filter = require('../controllers/filter.js');

exports.get = async function (req, res, next) {
  filter.validateId(req, res, next);
  const db = req.app.get('db');
  let id = req.params.id;
  let user;
  try {
    user = await db.models.user.findByPk(id);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
  res.json(user);
};
```

File structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0uBy.jpg)

But I get the error:

> { NotFoundError: Not Found
>       at E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\app.js:43:8
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15
>       at next (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:260:14)
>       at Function.handle (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at SendStream.error (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
>       at SendStream.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at SendStream.error (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\send\index.js:270:17)
>       at SendStream.onStatError (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\send\index.js:421:12)
>       at next (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\send\index.js:736:16)
>       at onstat (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\clone\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\send\index.js:725:14)
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21) message: 'Not Found' }
>   GET /4 404 48.713 ms - 100

Comment: Try to add all contents inside question post like the image, without referring to external links that may become unavailable in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `require` is pointed at the wrong location (assuming the code provided is in `userController.js`).

It should be:

```
const filter = require('./filter');
```